# Custom object lost property data after NSArray filter

Tags: ios, swift, properties, nsarray

I want to query a custom object from an `NSArray`, here is a function I wrote:

```
func retrieveObject (objects: [CustomClass], identifier : String) -> CustomClass {
    var retrievedObject : [CustomClass] = objects.filter({
        return $0.identifier == identifier
    })

    return retrievedObject.first!
}
```

When I use it, the resulted object seems to have lost most of the property values in that object:

```
let obj : CustomClass = self.retrieveObject(objectList as! [CustomClass], "one")
println("\(obj.propertyA)")
```

The result shows "", while printing the object from the original object list shows value:

```
println("\(objectList.first!.propertyA)")
```

What seems to be the issue?

**More Information:**

The objectList above is a result of an asynchronous web request, let's assume that the objects in it are problem-free because they return the correct property value when printed.

Code of one step above before the array filter:

```
private var objectList : [AnyObject]!
private var object : CustomClass

self.webRequest(request, onSuccess: {(objects: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    self.objectList = objects
    self.object = self.retrieveObject(self.objectList, identifier: "one") 
//I tried passing both self.objectList and objects
})
```

**Problem Solved**

**This is not an issue with Swift or whatever. This is a data issue. The above code works fine.**

Comment: Try this. objects.filter() {$0. identifier == identifier } in your retrieveObject method.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. It's basically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've provided us. I've recreated it in playgrounds and seems to print normally.

**Code:**

```
class CustomClass {
    let identifier: String
    let propertyA = "Printing!"

    init(identifier: String) {
        self.identifier = identifier
    }
}

let objectList = [CustomClass(identifier: "one")]

func retrieveObject (objects: [CustomClass], identifier: String) -> CustomClass {
    return objects.filter { $0.identifier == identifier }.first!
}

let object = retrieveObject(objectList, "one")
println("\(object.propertyA)")             // Prints "Printing!"
println("\(objectList.first!.propertyA)")  // Prints "Printing!"
```

**EDIT:**
Simplified it a bit

Comment: thanks for the response. It's very weird because the queried object carries the identifier, i.e. `println("\(object.identifier)")` prints "one", but `println("\(object.propertyA)")` returns an empty string.

Comment: Can you provide us more information? Like how `objectList` is created and perhaps `customClass`.

Comment: Are you sure the object returned from `retrieveObject(_:)` is the same as `objectList.first!`? Check in `retrieveObject(_:)` the count of `retrievedObject`.  Perhaps there are more objects with an identifier `"one"`? Also check whether `objectList.first!.identifier` is `"one"` as well.

Comment: good catch, but `retrievedObject` does only have one object inside. `objectList.first!.identifier` is not `"one"` because the object I need is not the first object, it would show another value e.g. `"five"`

Comment: this does give me an insight about what might be happening. I went back to check the response of that web request, and Baaaammm, the object that I need happens to have an empty value on `propertyA`!! What a silly situation. Sorry for wasting your time. I'll accept your reply as answer.

Comment: Heh thanks, glad you found it. Thought it would be too strange if they were the same since they both had a value (`""` and whatever value `objectList.first!.identifier` had). It's kinda risky to use `first!` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Except for line:

```
var retrievedObject : [CustomClass] = objects.filter({
        return $0.identifier == identifier
    })
```

that should be:

```
var retrievedObject : [CustomClass] = objects.filter { $0.identifier == identifier;};
```

In your version, you pass a strange value for filter argument (because of misplaced parenthesis) that does not match awaited filter argument type: `(T) -> Bool`

I tested Jacobson's code and I confirm it is working.

Comment: The parenthesis shouldn't matter though (still works without removing them). If it didn't, it would have crashed already when calling `.first!` too.

Comment: yes, the parenthesis did matter when a parameter was inside (the closure).

Comment: Have you tried `someArray.filter { $0 == value }` and `someArray.filter({ $0 == value })`? They both work.

Comment: You're right. I add a compile error `cannot invoke 'filter' with a parameter list of type '((_) -> _)' because I had a typo in my code: `({ $0.identifier = identifier })`. I made an assignation and not a comparison. Sorry.